# Change Format Date From "Fri, 18 Jul 2014" to 7/18/14 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am parsing an xls file and it has changed all my dates to this format `"Fri, 18 Jul 2014"` and i need it back to this format `"7/18/2014"` or to `"2014-07-18 17:00:00"`

I have tried to use `Chronic.parse()` with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first need to use [Date.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) to turn your string into a `Date` object and then use [Date#strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime).

```
Date.parse("Fri, 18 Jul 2014").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

A good website for playing around with the different formatting options is:

http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Comment: thanks that works... will accept when i can in 8 min

Answer (score 0):

You also have the [`localize()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper/localize) method of I18n ([a Rails' guide of Internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)):

```
I18n.localize(Date.current)
```

Uses the format defined for the current language in:

```
date:
  formats:
    default: "%Y-%m-%d"
    short: "%b %d"
    long: "%B %d, %Y"

# other formats' usage:
I18n.localize(Date.current, format: :long)
```

`.localize` has the same shorthand as `.translate`:

```
# in your views, you can simply do
Post's was created on <%= l(post.created_at, format: :long) %>
```

This method is very usefull since it relies on the end-user's language and can be easily changed. There is tons of helpers helping you dealing with Language AND dates (datetimes):

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words
- http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words

All using I18n translation system in order to follow each language's specification/translation.